# Creating a RAID 1 via mdadm ends with completely filled one of drives after sync

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid, mdadm, raid1

I have a server with 2x 1TB NVMe drives and I want them to work in software RAID 1 (mdadm) as a system drive.
After creating and waiting for sync of the array I'm ending with one of the drives in array as completely filled. Checking by `nvme list` or `df -h` shows that they looks like completely not synced. First I just grab a new server from Hetzner (Auctions) and after automatic install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and waiting for drives to resync I noticed this problem, removing this drive which is full and adding again to mdadm doesn't help. Already tested by reinstalling to 22.04 - same problem. And then manually formatting and setting up this array in Hetzner Rescue system. And I'm always ending with this after drive sync (both of them are just having clear OS on them)
I always end with `nvme list`:

```
    Node             SN                   Model                                    Namespace Usage                      Format           FW Rev
---------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- --------- -------------------------- ---------------- --------
/dev/nvme0n1     S3W6NX0Mxxxxxx       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000               1          19.80  GB /   1.02  TB    512   B +  0 B   EXA7301Q
/dev/nvme1n1     S3W6NX0Mxxxxxx       SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000               1           1.02  TB /   1.02  TB    512   B +  0 B   EXA7301Q
```

`lsblk`:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0   3.1G  1 loop
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0 920.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1
nvme1n1     259:4    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme1n1p1 259:8    0    32G  0 part
│ └─md0       9:0    0    32G  0 raid1
├─nvme1n1p2 259:9    0     1G  0 part
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1
└─nvme1n1p3 259:10   0 920.9G  0 part
  └─md2       9:2    0 920.7G  0 raid1
```

`fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x95d349e3

Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1          2048   67110911   67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p2      67110912   69208063    2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme0n1p3      69208064 2000407215 1931199152 920.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZVLB1T0HALR-00000
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x76027d35

Device         Boot    Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1          2048   67110911   67108864    32G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p2      67110912   69208063    2097152     1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/nvme1n1p3      69208064 2000407215 1931199152 920.9G fd Linux raid autodetect


Disk /dev/md0: 31.97 GiB, 34325135360 bytes, 67041280 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md1: 1022 MiB, 1071644672 bytes, 2093056 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md2: 920.74 GiB, 988638674944 bytes, 1930934912 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

`mdadm -D /dev/md2` (the biggest volume)

```
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Sep  2 01:43:35 2022
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 965467456 (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 965467456 (920.74 GiB 988.64 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Fri Sep  2 03:06:37 2022
             State : clean
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : rescue:2  (local to host rescue)
              UUID : 9140be20:6c29229f:d572b5ba:dee1f0a3
            Events : 895

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0     259        3        0      active sync   /dev/nvme0n1p3
       1     259       10        1      active sync   /dev/nvme1n1p3
```

and `cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md2 : active raid1 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      965467456 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/8 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md1 : active raid1 nvme1n1p2[1] nvme0n1p2[0]
      1046528 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md0 : active raid1 nvme1n1p1[1] nvme0n1p1[0]
      33520640 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

Everything looks normal to me, anybody know why the second drive ends as completely full after array resync?
Just to mention that this is not my first server on Hetzner - others one doesn't have differences in usage for similar configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The "resync" process means "make sure the data on the drives are consistent". Notice that MD RAID is a separate block level device which doesn't know anything about what's above it. Filesystems? No idea. LVM? Probably. Raw Oracle ASM tablespaces? Maybe. Isn't used at all? That happens. The MD RAID will keep working when assembled, and it will make sure all component devices are consistent with each other. It's all it could do, it's what it is designed for.

So, to make sure both RAID1 devices are consistent it just copies one to another block by block. Reads whatever one drive spits out and writes that to another. It doesn't care what data is stored in that block (and if that block is used by the filesystem); it just instructed that blocks from M to N of one device should be the same as blocks M to N on another device. Which means, at least one drive will be completely written during a resync.

What you can do to slightly relieve this situation is to trim the drive afterwards. You may send a trim command to the *RAID itself*, and if the passing down is enabled, it will convert that to NVMe commands. To check this you can do `lsblk --discard`. To do the trim, you can e.g. create a filesystem that spans the whole array and `fstrim` it.

Comment: This is a great answer!  I'd add that, so long as these drives weren't already your boot drives or something, you could use `nvme format` on both to prepare them.  Then create the array with `mdadm ... --assume-clean`.  Once the array is up, kick off a check (`echo check > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`) to make sure you did everything properly.